# How to create a class to call in multiple activities - Java android

Tags: java, android, class

I would like to create a class with this method:

```
int readNumber (int id){
    return Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(id)).getText().toString());
}
```

so, i can call it in my activities when needed.
Is that possible?
When i create a new java file with the method above, i get the error for the `findViewById(id)` . Thanks a lot

Comment: Pass the calling `View` to the method, then (assuming you're calling it `view`) do `view.findViewById(id)....` etc. But does this really need to be extracted to a method?

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to find a way to declare this method only once, and then call it when needed.